# JOINKEYS REFORMAT field for a VB file for F2 is not working

Tags: sorting, mainframe, dfsort

I am trying to right and left outer join these two RECFM VB files but
I don't get anything from the F2 file.

```
//STEP2000 EXEC PGM=SORT                          
//*   JOIN                                        
//*                                               
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                            
//*                                               
//SORTJNF1 DD DSN=YXX122.TEMP.EXPORT.TYPEN,   
//            DISP=SHR                            
//*                                               
//SORTJNF2 DD DSN=YXX122.TEMP.EXPORT.TYPEC,   
//            DISP=SHR                            
//*                                               
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=YXX122.DYXX122.EXPORT.XSUM,
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),            
//            UNIT=(DEV,2),                       
//            SPACE=(CYL,(150,20),RLSE),          
//            DCB=(RECFM=VB,LRECL=304,BLKSIZE=0)  
//*                                               
//SYSIN    DD *                                     
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                  
  JOINKEYS FILES=F1,                                
  FIELDS=(13,4,A,18,5,A,17,1,A,23,1,A,33,8,A,41,4,A)
  JOINKEYS FILES=F2,                                
  FIELDS=(13,4,A,18,5,A,17,1,A,23,1,A,33,8,A,41,4,A)
  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2                               
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:5,300)                        
  OUTFIL FTOV                                       
//
```

The problem is I can't find how the REFORMAT FIELDS the F2 file.

```
I tried with    REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:5,300,F2:5,300)  but the outfile was with a length of 600.
```

I will like to know how to have both file F1 and F2 in my SORTOUT file with a VB length 304.

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you have DFSORT, not SyncSORT which makes things simpler, as you can definitely use the Match Marker `?` in the REFORMAT statement. Up-to-date SyncSORT may have the Match Marker as an undocumented feature.

Putting all the unmatched records on one OUTFIL may be confusing (you won't know which input they have come from).

This conceptualises your join (where the Output is the joined data, and `b` represents blank).

```
F1
A
C
E

F2
B
C
F

Output
Ab
bB
Eb
bF
```

So if you want B and F you need to specify some data from F2. You also need to identify the "blanks" so that you know which part of the REFORMAT record currently has data in (DFSORT has a Match Marker for this, SyncSORT does not).

For that you need to identify one byte which can *never* be blank in the record. If that is not possible, one byte which can *never* be another given value (which you specify on FILL= on the REFORMAT). Failing that, two or more bytes with the same characteristics. As a final fail-safe you can check the entire part of the REFORMAT record from one file or the other for blank.

Since you want V-type output, you could make your REFORMAT record variable:

```
REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,4,?,F1:5,300,F2:5)
```

And use VLTRIM on OUTFIL.

Or fixed:

```
REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:5,300,F2:5,300)
```

And use FTOV with VLTRIM on OUTFIL.

Then you need some code, which tests the byte/bytes/partofdata you have chosen for being space/thevalueyouhavechosen and uses BUILD to create a record which contains the data you want (plus trailing blanks/values which will be killed by the VLTRIM).

```
 IFTHEN=(WHEN=(logicalexpression),
           BUILD=(1,4,5,300)),
 IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,
           BUILD=(1,4,305,300))
```

Or

```
 IFTHEN=(WHEN=(logicalexpression),
           BUILD=(1,300)),
 IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,
           BUILD=(301,300))
```

Here's some code which does what you want. Probably. I can't test it with SyncSORT.

Data:

```
F1
A 11111111111111111111111111111111111
C 2222222222222222222222 
E 3 

F2
B 4444444444444444 
C 55555555555555555555555555
F 6666666666666
```

Code:

OPTION COPY

JOINKEYS F1=INA,FIELDS=(5,1,A),SORTED,NOSEQCK
  JOINKEYS F2=INB,FIELDS=(5,1,A),SORTED,NOSEQCK
  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2,ONLY

REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,4,F1:5,76,F2:5)

OUTFIL FNAMES=EXT,VLTRIM=C' ', 
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(81,1,CH,EQ,C'2'), 
                   BUILD=(1,4,82)), 
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE, 
                   BUILD=(1,4,5,76))

The Match Marker, ?, will be set to `1` for unmatched F2, `2` for unmatched F2 and `B` for matched records (which you won't get, because of the `ONLY` on the `JOIN` statement).

This presumes your data is already in sequence. Remove the SORTED,NOSEQCK for data which is not in sequence.

I've used an LRECL of 80 and a simple key and some simple data.

Output:

```
For EXT:
A 11111111111111111111111111111111111
B 4444444444444444                   
E 3                                  
F 6666666666666
```

SORTOUT would show the unchanged REFORMAT record. That is for you to see how it works. You can remove the FNAMES=EXT or remove the SORTOUT from the JCL when you understand everything.

The F1:1,4 ensures that the REFORMAT record is variable-length. The 5,300 should use blank-padding for shorter records. That's why you need the VLTRIM later. The F2:5 says "file two, position five, to the end of the file two record".

If your data can have genuine trailing blanks, you'll have to use FILL= and VLTRIM= for the same character.

IFTHEN=(WHEN=(logicalexpression) processing finishes when an IFTHEN is true. So the combination in the code is effectively an IF/ELSE.

See also this, [Compare two files and write it to "match" and "nomatch" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792432/compare-two-files-and-write-it-to-match-and-nomatch-files?rq=1) and [Sync sort, Unpaired records of File1 have spaces for no records in F2 file. Can we replace those specific column's spaces by ZEROS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098504/sync-sort-unpaired-records-of-file1-have-spaces-for-no-records-in-f2-file-can?rq=1) for further examples.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer.  This is what I am trying to achieve here, I want to match F1 with F2.  It is possible we have no match, then I want all records to be in the output.   I am trying to have a left and right outter joint.  If I have a match then both records will not be on the output.   Our example

Comment: Maybe I should not use a join to accomplish this ?  The result of the output will be everything but not the intersection (the match).  I will like to preserve the output lenght exactly the same lenght as my input VB 304.  Both input files has the same length.  When I joint the length become 600 because of the REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:5,300,F2:5,300).  My problem seems to be the reformat or I should not use the Joinkey to perform what I am trying to do.  Thanks

Comment: at position 11 I have a 2 bytes characters with a filler which I can use.  How  can I make my logicalexpression to check if it is a blank at position 11 then I write starting at 301 for 300, else it will be at position 1 for 300. in this   IFTHEN=(WHEN=(logicalexpression),
           BUILD=(1,300)),
 IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,
           BUILD=(301,300))        because now if I use REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,4,F1:5,300,F2:5)   the F2 part is all blanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88811/discussion-between-user3127986-and-bill-woodger).